# Error messages in Matplotlib

Tags: python, file, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to chart this data in matplotlib and I am getting the following error message:

```
raise TypeError('Unrecognized argument type %s to close'%type(arg))
TypeError: Unrecognized argument type <type 'list'> to close
```

The data I am sending to it is not a string, it is a float as you can see from the code below:

```
import os
import csv
import glob as g
import pprint as p
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.chdir('F:\\')

def graphWriter():
    for file in g.glob('*.TXT'):
        for col in csv.DictReader(open(file,'rU')):
            set_ = int(col[' Set'])
            iriR = float(col[' IRI R e'])
            iriL = float(col['IRI LWP '])
            rutL = float(col[' RUT L e'])
            rutR = float(col[' RUT R e'])
            start = float(col['Start-Mi'])
            end = float(col['  End-Mi'])

    fig = plt.plot(iriR,iriL)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)

graphWriter()
```

Though the window is coming up to chart the data and the units are correct, there is also no line in the chart, probably that's stemming from the apparent data issue. So the question is whats causing the error message, and whats causing there to be no data lines in the chart. But the two are most likely related. Here is some of the input data though I am only trying to graph the  two datasets to the right side which would be iriR and iriL as show above:

```
(194.449, 194.549, 90.0, 77.9)
(194.549, 194.649, 84.6, 81.5)
(194.649, 194.749, 88.4, 84.1)
(194.749, 194.849, 69.5, 82.9)
(194.849, 194.949, 76.2, 71.0)
```

Comment: The `for` loop in your  function `graphWriter` seems to have a bad indentation. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct though it is fixed now. That error was just from the copy paste and is not in the IDE

Comment: In which line it breaks?

Comment: And can you show an example of the input file?

Comment: well its hard to say where it breaks. When I just do a yield of the data it works fine. The dialog box shows, there is just no line. Then after I close the dialog box for the graph, the error message shows in the python shell.

Comment: Ok I posted some input data though it has been formatted by the program. The original input file is a mess but this is how the data would look coming into the matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function [`plt.plot` returns a list of lines](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) (that were added to the plot), and not a `Figure` object --- while `plt.close` only accepts a `Figure` object.  There are numerous ways to work around this,

First, get the figure object ("**g**et **c**urrent **f**igure"):

```
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.close(fig)
```

Second, call close with no arguments: `plt.close()` --- this will automatically close the active figure.

Third, close all figures: `plt.close('all')`.

[All of these usages are covered in the matplotlib.pyplot.close documentation.](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.close)

### Edit:

The next issue is that you're not storing an array of values to your variables, instead you're just storing a single floating value.  You can initialize a list, and store new elements to it.

```
os.chdir('F:\\')
iriR = []   # Initialize a list

def graphWriter():
    for file in g.glob('*.TXT'):
        for col in csv.DictReader(open(file,'rU')):
            set_ = int(col[' Set'])
            iriR.append(float(col[' IRI R e']))   # Append new entry
```

Do the same thing for the other variables that you want to plot.

Comment: So should I still have fig = plt.plot(iriR,iriL)?

Comment: @hollow_Victory no... then you'd be rewriting that variable.

Comment: That solves the error issue but there chart is still blank

Comment: @hollow_Victory that's because your variables `iriR` and `iriL` are just holding single values from the last column of the last file you open.  You can always use a print statement to look at your variables, e.g. `print(iriR)`.  I've edited my answer to fix this as-well.

Comment: Ya I was hoping I wouldn't have to make a list for every variable. I knew this would probably work and it does so ok ill do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob as g

def graphWriter():
    data = {}
    for file in g.glob('*.TXT'):
        data[file] = pd.read_csv(file)
        # Removes ')' and turn it into float
        data[file][3] = data[file][3].apply(lambda x:x[:-1]).astype(float)

    fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

    for d in data.itervalues():
        ax.plot(d[:,2], d[:,3])

    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)

graphWriter()
```

The function will obtain a list of files ended in `.TXT` then it will load  them into a dictionary in which the keys are the names of the files. Later will plot them.

**Update**

Since the OP posted that `pandas` is unavailable, its is possible to use `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob as g

def graphWriter():
    data = {}
    for file in g.glob('*.TXT'):
        data[file] =  np.fromregex(file, '\d*\.\d*', 
                                   dtype=[('1', float), ('2', float),
                                          ('3', float), ('4', float)])

    fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

    for d in data.itervalues():
        ax.plot(d['3'], d['4'])

    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)

graphWriter()
```

Comment: Very nice but it produced the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: Line,

Comment: But I just realized that is not iterating properly through the dataset. I think it just stops at the first row. That's my code im referring to right now.

Comment: The `numpy.loadtxt` probably didn't work because of the parentheses in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: @hollow_Victory I updated it. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I cant import Pandas anymore. Ive tried and I don't know why I lost that. Im at work and it happened when we updated the systems

Comment: @hollow_Victory Thanks. And what about `numpy`? I added an update.

Comment: I can import numpy. It doesn't like the file 'test'. but that shoudnt matter. You don't need to worry about using regex since I can tell it what to bring into the matplot by column name. That why I use this design.